# How can I select the first option inside a dropdown menu by targeting css?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm currently using Cucumber / Selenium / Ruby to create my automation framework and setup my first test. The one I'm working on involves me to fill in a form in order to proceed to the next stage. The form contains a dropdown with multiple values, of which I want to select one (and any one!)

**Inspect Element of the Dropdown Menu**

```
<input type="search" class="ember-power-select-trigger-multiple-input" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" id="ember-power-select-trigger-multiple-input-ember3325" aria-controls="ember-power-select-options-ember3325" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="All classes">
```

I've therefore made use of the `class` inside my step below:

**My Step**

```
@wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => 'input.ember-power-select-trigger-multiple-input').click}
```

At the moment, when I run this, it's able to find the correct dropdown option and click it. The options in the list appear, but obviously nothing happens.

What I'd like to know is how I can extend this further so that the dropdown is selected, and that the "first" option is selected? I don't want to specify what it should be, but it just should randomly select the first from the list and use that.

Any thoughts on the easiest way to achieve this?

---

**Research Snippet**
I did some research and found the following snippet which I thought I could add to my code, however I'm unsure if it would actually work, or whether I could use this in conjunction with the `@wait.until` step that I mentioned above?

```
groupDropdown = @driver.find_element(:css => 'input.ember-power-select-trigger-multiple-input')
option = groupDropdown.find_element(:css, "option:nth-child(1)")
option.click
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => 'input.ember-power-select-trigger-multiple-input').click}
@wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => '.ember-view > li > .ember-view > li:nth-of-type(1) > .ember-view > li').click}
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

### Until

The “until” method within Selenium requires a “truthy” response to continue with the rest of the code.

What you could do is this:

```
power_select = @driver.find_element(:css => 'input.ember-power-select-trigger-multiple-input')
@wait.until {power_select.displayed?}
power_select.click
```

This will wait for the element to be displayed on the page, which returns a boolean, and then follow through with a click

### Select

Following on from that, the methods for Selects are hidden within the library quite well, but after searching around for a bit:

To Select by text:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:css => <insert_css_of_select_here>)).select_by(:text, <insert_option_text_here>)
```

To Select by index:

```
Selenium::Webdriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:css => <insert_css_of_select_here>)).select_by(:index, <insert_index_value_here>)
```

Selecting by index is what you most likely want to do here, setting the index value to 0 to select the first option.

Comment: Thanks Kyle
I found that the following worked for me:

`@wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => 'input.ember-power-select-trigger-multiple-input').click}`
`@wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => '.ember-view > li > .ember-view > li:nth-of-type(1) > .ember-view > li').click}`

Answer (score 0):

This will let you select required option of ember-power-select with Capybara:

```
find('.ember-power-select-trigger').click # Open trigger
find_all('ul.ember-power-select-options > li')[1].click # Select 2nd option
```

Tested with latest ember-power-select.

You might find the click be quite slow if your `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` is high, so to speed things further you can do this:

```
find('.ember-power-select-trigger').click # Open trigger
Capybara.using_wait_time(0.1) do
  find_all('ul.ember-power-select-options > li')[1].click # Select 2nd option
end
```